# Avg AntiVirus Professional Scalability?

Tags: networking, anti-virus, scalability

With the Network editions of AVG Anti virus for business, how well does it scale? How many users can it support on one network? I have heard a few stories of business's with about 3000 computers under their administration and the avg administration had problems dealing with that many users.  Maybe it was just bad IT administration/planning or is the product just not made for large business support? I know this is a little vague, but I am not seeing any information regarding the number of clients supported or clients supported per administration server.

Answer (score 3):

I can't tell you about 3000, but we handle around 100 users from two minimal Win2k3 VMware virtual machines on relatively old servers (~5 years) and no problems to speak of. We have 1 server per site and that seems to work well. The updates are centralized, so you have to budget for a bunch of machines all trying to update at the same time.

When I've used Symantec in the past, I liked it's random time options where you could give it a time window instead of everyone hitting the server to update at once.

One solution would be to put different groups of users into different admin groups and assigning updates at different times.

Comment: I can bet it was an issue when 3000 machines try and update all at once.